# Webpack includes unused library in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, webpack

I don't understand why...

Include like 100Kbytes of a unused library:

```
/*!
 * The buffer module from node.js, for the browser.
 *
 * @author   Feross Aboukhadijeh <feross@feross.org> <http://feross.org>
 * @license  MIT
 */
...
...
```

My `webpack.deploy.config.js`

```
    'use strict';

/* eslint-env node */

const webpack = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const config = {
  addVendor: function (name, path) {
    this.resolve.alias[name] = path;
    this.module.noParse.push(new RegExp(`^${name}$`));
  },

  node: {
    Buffer: false,
    global: false,
    process: false,
    setImmediate: false
  },

  entry: {
    app: [
      './src/main.jsx'
    ],
    vendors: [
      'jquery',
      'semantic',
      'semantic.css',
      'react',
      'react-dom'
    ]
  },

  resolve: { alias: {} },

  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/build`,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: './src/static', to: './' }]),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('app', null, false),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendors', 'vendors.js'),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery'
    })
  ],

  module: {
    noParse: [],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx)?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js)$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /bower_components/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css)$/,
        loader: 'style!css'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(less)$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ]
  }
};

config.addVendor('jquery', `${__dirname}/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js`);
config.addVendor('semantic', `${__dirname}/bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js`);
config.addVendor('semantic.css', `${__dirname}/bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.css`);
config.addVendor('react', `${__dirname}/bower_components/react/react.min.js`);
config.addVendor('react-dom', `${__dirname}/bower_components/react/react-dom.min.js`);

module.exports = config;
```

I am using `es6` with `babel` and `react`, the code works well, just trying to minify the package.

Also uses a cross library (node/browser) that use `http` and `https`, but I think its not the problem.

Comment: How do you know it's not used? You can check what uses it inside a bundle.

Comment: @zerkms hi, was the cross library, all that extra code is from `http` and `https`, the solution is bundle the library with browserify with the options **.external('http').external('https')** and then in the webpack used the result library like a vendor...

Answer (score 4):

I faced the similar problem when migrated from webpack1 to webpack2. The bundle size increased from 125kb to 164kb (minimized).

Looks like the major part takes the buffer library which presumably comes from css-loader and adds source-map support.

I opened an issue https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader/issues/194 and looks like the simple workaround is to add `node: {Buffer: false}` to the webpack config. Read more at: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/node/